# Angular http-server url-rewrite

Tags: angular, url-rewriting

I have to move Angular application from IIS to some http server in Linux.
I'm trying http-server but there isn't url-rewrite module and I can't reload angular page. Do I need to install another web server? Apache http-server for example?
Thanks in advance.